# Weblogic 10.3 web console does not work

Tags: java, logging, weblogic

Jdeveloper 11.1.1.6 is installed on my computer. IntegratedWeblogicServer 10.3 works without problem. I just installed Jdeveloper 11.1.2.3 version and did not import ex ide version preferences into new installation while firstly opening.
I started integrated weblogic server from new version of jdeveloper then created new domain and server switched in running mode without any errors. But when i try to open webconsole throughout localhost:7101/console. (additionaly ex server still works normal, i have tried that shutdown new one, and opening the old server)
Even if i copied some lib jars into wlhome\lib folder but no positive result (wllog4j.jar, commons-logging.jar, com.bea.core.weblogic.commons.logging_1.4.0.0.jar)
What might be the problem?
the exception is below

```
<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "ResourceServlet" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "console".
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
  at com.bea.console.resource.http.ResourceServlet.<clinit>(ResourceServlet.java:54)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
  Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
...
```

brgds

Answer (score 0):

Could you make sure you have commons-logging.jar file in the classpath.

You can download it from the apache site.  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/download_logging.cgi

Comment: "Even if i copied some lib jars into wlhome\lib folder but no positive result (wllog4j.jar, commons-logging.jar, com.bea.core.weblogic.commons.logging_1.4.0.0.jar) "